# What is the equivalent AMD API for Custom Resolution and Sync Timing to the NDA version of NVAPI of NVIDIA?

Tags: c++, windows, screen-resolution, amd-processor, nvapi

The question says it all. Does AMD have an API for setting a custom resolution in Windows with custom sync timing (in c++)?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about you have tagged [tag:amd] (please read the info there, was this what you meant?). As for your questions about timing resolutions and c++, have a look at [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think he means custom display resolution and sync/refresh stuff on AMD/ATI cards, true about the tag though, probably not what was expected.

Comment: 1) I meant AMD the graphics card company. 
2) I asked about custom monitor resolution and sync timing (monitor sync pulses timing) NOT C++ timing resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I found out: It's the ADL (AMD Display Library) Public API. There is an ADL SDK 7 to download.
In contrast to NVIDIA, you can get similar functionality without waiting for months (most likely for ever as the vast majority of us has experienced), for an NDA version.